# accessing history in a firefox addon

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, browser-history

I'm working on a firefox addon, using the addon builder. I want to periodically scan the browser's history.. the entire history. I'm looking for functionality like [chrome's history api](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history.html). It seems [window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history) is limited to session history only. Any help? I'm going crazy trying to figure this out. Addons like [history export](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/history-export/?src=api) must do something like this, but their code is not immediately understandable to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to access the xpcom service [nsIBrowserHistory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIBrowserHistory), here's some example code that works with the SDK:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/157396/latest/

The places api is a bit verbose, there are extensive examples available on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Querying_Places

There is also a module developed by Mozilla community members available here that provides some abstractions:

https://github.com/autonome/Jetpack-Modules/blob/master/places.js

I'm not sure if theabove module has been tested against recent versions of Firefox and the SDK.

Comment: What a hero answer. Really helpful example code and links. I've got what I want now, thanks so much!