# Is possible read the browser history with JS?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

Is possible read the browser history with Javascript? If the answer is Yes, how can I do it?
I want to read it and save it in a JS variable.

Comment: I hope not ... Do you want to have any arbitrary website to be able to know what other sites you looked at?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FManipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Other sites visited by a user are their business, not the business of every website they visit. Browsers do not expose that information to web sites.

Browsers go to [pretty serious lengths to plug anything that could leak a user's history to websites](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2010/03/31/plugging-the-css-history-leak/)

Comment: How do ads know what products I was looking at amazon and so on?!

Comment: @user1389840 — Browsers have plugged that security hole

Comment: @EddyUnruh — Advertisers + third party cookies

Answer (score 1):

In general history is protected by the browser against javascript accessing it except through back and forward functionality.

Source From : [Access my entire browsing history via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369829/access-my-entire-browsing-history-via-javascript)