# Is there any way to AccessAll the search history of Browser with out using any API

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

my question  is How can i access all the history of Browser without using any API ?

I search out lot to get answer of this Question but i Didn't get proper answer so please give me suggestion or reference  ..

Comment: which browser? IE, Mozilla, Chrome?

Comment: Not For Specific Browser...

Comment: It is not possible, and it's very good. Just consider - will you be happy, if some website easily gets access to your browsing history?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox use to store these info in SQLITE database file, so this can be read from a file called as *places*. But you should have local access to that path. From a website this is generally not possible. From a Browser addin, this is possible easily.

Comment: sarvesh can please give me brief detail about how to access places file through  browser addin..

Comment: Please see this stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369829/access-my-entire-browsing-history-via-javascript