# In Selenium, can I get the last URL visited without actually navigating there?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm aware that I can navigate backwards through my history using the **IWebDriver.Navigate().Back()** method, but what if I just need the URL of the last page visited?  Is there a way to grab that from the WebDriver, without actually navigating there?

To be clear, this is a question about Selenium WebDriver, and has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: I've used Selenium in the past and I'm not aware of any way to do that. I also checked the documentation, Google and tried to find something using Intelisense in Visual Studio but didn't come up with anything. You would have to maintain a list (or stack) of URLs yourself to do that.

Comment: @Gilles - Yeah, same here.  I was hoping to avoid that, but if WebDriver has no way to peek in on its browse history, then that's what I'll do.  Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access my entire browsing history via Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369829/access-my-entire-browsing-history-via-javascript)

Comment: Refer [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8737/navigate-to-previous-page-using-selenium) post it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by several, what I ended up doing is wrapping the Selenium WebDriver in my own class that monitors all navigation, and keeps its own history.  It seems a redundancy, given that somewhere deep in the bowels of WebDriver another history already exists, but since the tester doesn't have access to it, I see no other way of achieving this goal.

Thanks to all who contributed their thoughts and suggestions!

Comment: I know its an old post, but can you better explain how you did this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep the previous page URL in a variable and update/pass it to the actual code that needs it. Even keep a collection of all visited URLs and just get the last item, all this will give you a history without any need for JS hacks. Storing and sharing state is a valid case, already implemented in some frameworks, like SpecFlow's [ScenarioContext](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/ScenarioContext). And the previous page URL value will be available to all your steps/code for each test.