# Search window.history page stack

Tags: javascript, browser-history, session-storage

I couldn't find anything on the web: is there a function to search the window.history page stack? I'd like to find out if a user has already visited a page without using cookies or sessionStorage?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access my entire browsing history via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369829/access-my-entire-browsing-history-via-javascript)

Comment: Hm, kind of, thx, but is there a way of determining if the user has already visited a page? On an AJAXED page, I'd like to use window.scrollTo(0,0) if the page has not been visited yet. Preferably without using cookies or similar storage containers.

Comment: You'll want to actually read the answers to the linked questions in full to find out the answer. Which is no.

Comment: @Anna You could use localStorage (you haven't excluded that one) or use a server-side tracking API where you would record the visit.

Answer (score 0):

"For security reasons the History object doesn't allow the non-privileged code to access the URLs of other pages in the session history, but it does allow it to navigate the session history."  - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history)

Comment: Which is not a reason to discredit a valid answer. I forgot to check for duplicates and vote to close now.

Comment: A duplicate answer is not useful.

Comment: Why vote to close!? My follow up question is: 
On an AJAXED page, I'd like to use window.scrollTo(0,0) if the page has not been visited yet. Preferably without using cookies or similar storage containers.

Comment: @Anna Like I said ideally you'd have to use `localStorage`, `cookies` OR a server-side tracking mechanism (better control on tracking lifetime). The `:visited` idea of the other answer is also interesting as long as you hide the implementation details away.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll look into that and into the :visited approach!

Comment: What is non-privileged code?

Comment: The JS code executing on a web-page is non-privileged while JS code from an extension is priviledged. See [MDN ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/privileged_code).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to make use of the css styling the `:visited` selector for an `a` tag.  Put a hidden div on your page that contains an `a` tag with its href set to the first page.  Add a css style for it using [visited selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp) and then check the styling of the `a` tag to see if it matches that styling.

Comment: This is precisely why the browser makers stopped honoring the `:visited` pseudo selector; spammers and other malcontents tracking people's activity on the web.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Indeed - that's one advantage of using old versions of browsers ;o)  But, being serious, if I wanted to know if a user has visited one of my pages, I would do something on the page to register that fact and not try to hack into a user's private data to find out.  I'm just putting this Question on the pile with "I **need** to see a user's local files/cookies/all localStorage/details of extensions they are using etc etc etc"  However, I thought it was being kept for the same protocal/domain/port pages - like localStorage?