# What is the URI "places:" schema in "Places query URIs" in Web API / browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser, webapi

I saw some [old (2014) StackOverflow answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22773361/21120611)r mentioning the term "Places query URIs", providing a [broken link to Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Places_query_URIs).

I tried to

- search Google for the "places:" schema
- explore the modern "Location" API, trying to find some clues

All I could find is a [mysterious cached/archived version of the possibly original](https://developer.mozilla.org.cach3.com/en/Places_query_URIs) old webpage from MDN, and [another archived webpage explaining the Places thing](https://developer.mozilla.org.cach3.com/en/Places). It's from at least 2016, and claims that:

> Places is the bookmarks and history management system introduced in Firefox 3. It offers increased flexibility and complex querying to make handling the places the user goes easier and more convenient. It also includes new features including favicon storage and the ability to annotate pages with arbitrary information. It also introduces new user interfaces for managing all this information; see Places on the Mozilla wiki.
>
> Places stores its data in an SQLite database using the mozStorage interfaces.

2016 is so before the Common Era? No one uses this API? no browser supports it? Even no one documents it as a deprecated feature? no backward-compatibility?

What's the straightforward alternative to it?

What was the exact goal of it? Why it's gone?

My goal was to manipulate the session history, trying to learn the possible capabilities beyond "History" API

Comment: it was just an abandoned firefox feature/api, not a web platform thing. what are you trying to accomplish with regards to history that the standard API's don't permit?